# React Mui-Dropzone Using multiple Dropzone on the same page

Tags: reactjs, dropzone

Im trying to using React with Mui-dropzone to handle fileupload. I want to use multiple Dropzone component in one page. I have tried saving the files in the state(nested objects), but the file always saved in my last state, what just happened?, and how do i store each of the files independent on each state?

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    firstFile: [],
    secondFile: []
  });

  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  function handleDialog() {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  }

  function onSaveFirstFile(file) {
    setData(prevState => ({
      ...data,
      firstFile: [...prevState.firstFile, file]
    }))
    setIsOpen(false);
  }

  function onSaveSecondFile(file) {
    setData(prevState => ({
      ...data,
      secondFile: [...prevState.secondFile, file]
    }))
    setIsOpen(false);
  }

  function showState() {
    console.log(data)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
{/* ------------------------------
 --------First Dropzone 
 ------------------------------ */}

      <Link classes={{ root: classes.linkRoot }} onClick={handleDialog}>
        <Typography variant="body2">Upload first File</Typography>
      </Link>
      <DropzoneArea
        dropzoneClass={classes.dropZoneRoot}
      />
      <DropzoneDialog
        open={isOpen}
        acceptedFiles={["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/bmp"]}
        showPreviews={true}
        maxFileSize={5000000}
        showFileNamesInPreview={true}
        onDelete={deleteFileObj => {
          console.log("OnDelete", deleteFileObj);
        }}
        onClose={() => {
          console.log("OnClose : ", data);
          setIsOpen(false);
        }}
        onSave={onSaveFirstFile}
      />
      <br />

 {/* ------------------------------
 --------Second Dropzone 
 ------------------------------ */}
      <Link classes={{ root: classes.linkRoot }} onClick={handleDialog}>
        <Typography variant="body2">Upload second File</Typography>
      </Link>
      <DropzoneArea
        dropzoneClass={classes.dropZoneRoot}
      />
      <DropzoneDialog
        open={isOpen}
        acceptedFiles={["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/bmp"]}
        showPreviews={true}
        maxFileSize={5000000}
        showFileNamesInPreview={true}
        onDelete={deleteFileObj => {
          console.log("OnDelete", deleteFileObj);
        }}
        onClose={() => {
          console.log("OnClose : ", data);
          setIsOpen(false);
        }}
        onSave={onSaveSecondFile}
      />
      <br />
      <button onClick={showState}>Show State!</button>
    </div>
```

this is what i got in the console after uploading the file on the first Dropzone(it saved in the wrong state, why?)

```
Object {firstFile: Array[0], secondFile: Array[1]}
```

note : this is my codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-mui-dropzone-4fwlb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  function handleDialog() {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  }
```

Both `DropzoneDialog` open via this function. When you click either, you set `open={true}` on both. Your files are always uploading to the `secondFile` array, because your first DropZone is always hidden behind the second one.

Comment: pardon me, did you mean i should using different state to control each state of the dialog?

Comment: That's up to you. Instead of a boolean your state could be a string (or number), and then something along the lines of `open={myState === /* some value */}`. Either way you need to make sure to not open both dialogs simultaneously. Only one `open` prop should evaluate to a truthy value at any given time.